# Scala Intersection of List and Option of list

Tags: scala, intersect

I was trying to do something on scala REPL when i came across this one. Suppose i have a list say

```
val list1:List[String]=List("test1","test2")
```

and i have something like this

```
val list2:Option[List[String]]=Some(List("test1"))
```

I was trying my hands on intersect method and tried this

```
list2.getOrElse(List.empty).intersect(list1)
```

i was expecting the result to be List("test1") instead i got an empty list. What am i missing here?

Comment: Your code returns what you expect without any problem

Comment: I think `list2.map(_.intersect(list1)).getOrElse(List.empty)` is more logical decision. And there is no `intersect` for `None`.

Comment: That seems a good option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm. I can't reproduce the issue:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_31).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val list1:List[String]=List("test1","test2")
list1: List[String] = List(test1, test2)

scala> val list2:Option[List[String]]=Some(List("test1"))
list2: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(test1))

scala> list2.getOrElse(List.empty).intersect(list1)
res0: List[String] = List(test1)
```

Comment: I seem to be using scala 2.10.4. Do you think it was issue wrt scala version?

Comment: @Rakshith No - I just tried this in 2.10.4, and it gives the result you expect.

Comment: Seems like all of a sudden it is working fine. I closed the repl and opened it again.

Answer (score 2):

Using `fold` might be a more idiomatic approach.

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val list1:List[String]=List("test1","test2")
val list2:Option[List[String]]=Some(List("test1"))  // first try it with Some()

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

list1: List[String] = List(test1, test2)
list2: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(test1))

scala> list2.fold(List[String]()){_.intersect(list1)}
res22: List[String] = List(test1)

scala> val list2:Option[List[String]]=None  // now try it with None
list2: Option[List[String]] = None

scala> list2.fold(List[String]()){_.intersect(list1)}
res23: List[String] = List()
```